# How can i clear can buffer?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, buffer, can-bus

I am trying to receive data about current angle from engine to raspbery pi and rotate based on received angle + one gradus. Engine send me data angle constantly. But when I read buffer i can only see first message that i get from it. Why buffer can not be cleared?

```
void canutil()//SET CAN
{
        int ret;
        rele_on_flag =1;
    
        system("sudo ip link set can1 type can bitrate 1000000");//1000000
        system("sudo ifconfig can1 up");
        system("sudo ifconfig can1 txqueuelen 65536");//65536
        
        put_info_in_global("can is "," configured","");
        show_info_lcd();

        //.Create socket
        s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);
        if (s < 0)
        {
            perror("socket PF_CAN failed");
            put_info_in_global("socket can"," failed","");
            show_info_lcd();
        }
        strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "can1");
        ret = ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            perror("ioctl failed");
            put_info_in_global("ioctl can"," failed","");
            show_info_lcd();
        }
        addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
        addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
        ret = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            perror("bind failed");
            put_info_in_global("bind can"," failed","");
            show_info_lcd();
        };
};
```

How I receive data:

```
float receive_data_angle(int id_driver) // get angle from engine depends on the id driver
{
        float frame_data;
         frame1.data[0] = 0;
                frame1.data[1] = 0;
                frame1.data[2] = 0;
                frame1.data[3] = 0;
                frame1.data[4] = 0;
                frame1.data[5] = 0;
                frame1.data[6] = 0;
                frame1.data[7] = 0;
        nbytes=0;

        nbytes = read(s0, &frame1, sizeof(frame1));

        struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_usec=100;
        ioctl(s0,SIOCGSTAMP_OLD,&tv);

        int can_id = 0x900+id_driver;
        int frame_can_id = frame1.can_id<<2;
        frame_can_id = frame_can_id>>2;
        if(frame_can_id==can_id)
        {
            if(nbytes > 0) {

                int frame_1 =(frame1.data[0]<<8|frame1.data[1]);
                frame_data = ((float)frame_1/16383.0*360.0);//1000000;
                 return frame_data;
            }
        }

}
```

func for rotate:

```
`void rotate_angle(int id_driver, floatgradus) 
{
        rele_on_start();
        int numbed=0x04FF;//<<8 | id_driver;
        numbed=numbed|(1<<31);
        frame.can_id = numbed;
        frame.can_dlc = 4;
        frame.len=4;
        int gr = 100;
        gr=(int)(gradus*1000000);

        frame.data[0] = gr>>24;
        frame.data[1] = gr>>16;
        frame.data[2] = gr>>8;
        frame.data[3] = gr;
        nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(frame));
};`
```

how I try to use it:
float angle;

```
while(1)
{
angle = receive_data_angle(id);
rotate_angle(id,angle+1);
}
```

I am also try to receive angle using different thread or call function for rotate only when interrupts happend. Same problem.
I also try to read buffer that many times while it didnt be cleared, but it is stable first received angle.

Comment: `struct timeval tv; tv.tv_usec=100; ioctl(s0,SIOCGSTAMP_OLD,&tv);` looks questionable  as `tv.tv_sec` is not set.

Comment: I don't know this specific hardware, but in case of a CAN controller with Rx FIFO, it is custom/best practice to always read the whole FIFO and process every message until you empty the FIFO.

Comment: @Lundin I suppose this may happen because i receive messages via can too fast and I can clear only part of buffer idk...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica how could it be?

Comment: If you have a queue in your program filling up faster than your software can handle it, then the whole system design is broken. Start with reviewing real-time requirements then take it from there.